# I am trying to get the data from json in html. I don't want to use Ajax because

Tags: javascript, html

I ma learning `XMLHttpRequest`. 
JSON data is not loading.
For some reason I am not getting the value of my json data. 
My code

```
function foo() {
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.open('GET', "data.json",true);
    httpRequest.send();
    var abc =  httpRequest.responseText;
}
```

My Json Data

```
[
    {
        ID : 0,
        VALUE : "United State"
    },{
        ID : 1,
        VALUE : "United Kingdom"
    },{
        ID : 2,
        VALUE : "Afghanistan"
    },{
        ID : 3,
        VALUE : "Aland Islands"
    },{
        ID : 4,
        VALUE : "Albania"
    }
]
```

What I am making wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing an [`onreadystatechange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) event handler, which is how you actually get the data:

```
function foo() {
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.open('GET', "data.json",true);
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && httpRequest.status === 200) {
            console.log(httpRequest.responseText);
        }
    };
    httpRequest.send();
}
```

If you need to work with that data outside of your function, you can use the callback pattern:

```
function foo(callback) {
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.open('GET', "data.json",true);
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && httpRequest.status === 200) {
            // trigger your callback function
            callback(httpRequest.responseText);
        }
    };
    httpRequest.send();
}

foo(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Or [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

```
function foo(callback) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.open('GET', "data.json",true);
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && httpRequest.status === 200) {
            // trigger your callback function
            resolve(httpRequest.responseText);
        }
    };
    httpRequest.send();
  });
}

foo().then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Worked. Awesome !!

Comment: What If I need data from external source. Can I write this `foo(callback,url)`

Comment: Yep! Though traditionally the callback is the last argument (not that it really matters)